# better heuristic then A*

Tags: algorithm, search, heuristics, a-star

I am enrolled in Stanford's ai-class.com and have just learned in my first week of lecture about a* algorithm and how it's better used then other search algo.

I also show one of my class mate implement it on 4x4 sliding block puzzle which he has published at: http://george.mitsuoka.org/StanfordAI/slidingBlocks/
While i very much appreciate and thank George to implement A* and publishing the result for our amusement.

I (and he also) were wondering if there is any way to make the process more optimized or if there is a better heuristic A*, like better heuristic function than the max of "number of blocks out of place" or "sum of distances to goals" that would speed things up?
and Also if there is a better algo then A* for such problems, i would like to know about them as well.

Thanks for the help and in case of discrepancies, before down grading my profile please allow me a chance to upgrade my approach or even if req to delete the question, as am still learning the ways of stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you tried searching for A* alternatives?

Comment: i first tried as u said before asking the question but there were no satisfactory results, one off them is blobmap algo. so It thought it would be a better approach to ask it here. (BDW thanks GollezTrol for responding)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your [heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_function). for example, if you have a perfect heuristic [`h*`], then a [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) algorithm(*), will yield better result then A*, and will still be optimal [since your heuristic is perfect!]. It will develop only the nodes needed for the solution. Unfortunately, it is seldom the case that you have a perfect heuristic.

(*)greedy algorithm: always develop the node with the lowest `h` value.

However, if your heuristic is very bad: `h=0`, then A* is actually a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)! And A* in this case will develop `O(B^d)` nodes, where B is the branch factor and d is the number of steps required for solving.

In this case, since you have a single target function, a [bi-directional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) (*) will be more efficient, since it needs to develop only `O(2*B^(d/2))=O(B^(d/2))` nodes, which is much less then what A* will develop.

bi directional search: (*)run BFS from the target and from the start nodes, each iteration is one step from each side, the algorithm ends when there is a common vertex in both fronts.

For the average case, if you have a heuristic which is not perfect, but not completely terrbile, A* will probably perform better then both solutions.

**Possible optimization for average case**: You also can run bi-directional search with A*: from the start side, you can run A* with your heuristic, and a regular BFS from the target side. Will it get a solution faster? no idea, you should probably benchmark the two possibilities and find which is better. However, the solution found with this algorithm will also be optimal, like BFS and A*.

Comment: thanks Amit, for clarifying. I have modified the question and would like hear from your pt if the approach taken for 4x4 puzzle is appropriate or is there a considerable space for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of A* is based on the quality of the expected cost heuristic, as you learned in the videos.  Getting your expected cost heuristic to match as closely as possible to the actual cost from that state will reduce the total number of states that need to be expanded.  There are also a number of variations that perform better under certain circumstances, like for instance when faced with hardware restrictions in large state space searching.